# Unit Test can't find Core Data model file

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, unit-testing, ocunit

I've created a project with a Core Data model in it. The application looks for the model file (.momd) and runs just fine.

Unfortunately, the unit test keeps returning null:

```
NSURL *dataModelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

I can see the myDataModel.xdatamodeld folder and file in BOTH the main target and the unit testing target's Compile Sources directory - but that doesn't seem to be enough. What else am I missing in the unit test target?

Thanks,
-Luther

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that you have to add your data model to the *test project's* Compiled Sources listing. That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unfortunately, a unit test target does not use the application's main bundle but it creates a special UnitTest-bundle. So if you need to use bundled resources (like a Core Data model) within your tests, you need to work around that issue.

The most simple and most flexible workaround would be using the `bundleForClass:` method of `NSBundle` within your testing code. The parameter for that method can simply be given by `[self class]` within your tests. That way you can reuse this code without having to adjust the bundle identifiers in multiple projects.

Example:

```
- (void)testBundleLocation
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"myDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: @LutherBaker While this seems to be the best workaround among all solutions for now, I do not think this is the *right* answer. Unit testing should not require one to modify the application source. So while here you're accessing the bundle in the test case, doing a `bundleForClass:` seems okay, but if you have some application code that does a `[NSBundle mainBundle]` (a common enough idiom, and not deprecated AFAIK), that class cannot be unit tested.

Comment: Thank you so much. Lost two solid days trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 6):

The answer has to do with the bundle. A unit test target doesn't use the 'main' bundle. It creates its own bundle which, in my case, defaulted to 'com.yourcompany.UnitTest' - straight out of the [Target]-info.plist.

The corrected solution then looks like this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.yourcompany.UnitTests"];
NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"myDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

Thanks

Comment: This answer is good as well, because it provides all the information you need to understand and fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem, i solved it using the OCMock framework, so i did not need to change the application code

```
@interface TestCase()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id bundleMock;
@end

@implementation TestCase

- (void)setUp
{
    self.bundleMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSBundle class]];
    [[[self.bundleMock stub] andReturn:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]] mainBundle];
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    [self.bundleMock stopMocking];
    [super tearDown];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method will get your bundle from any target. However, for each target you add, you have to manually add the plist bundle identifier to the `identifiers` array, because there is no way to get it programmatically. The advantage is that you can use the same code for testing or running the application.

```
+(NSBundle*) getBundle 
{
    NSBundle *bundle = nil;

    // try your manually set bundles
    NSArray *identifiers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"com.your.application",
                                                      @"com.your.test",
                                                      nil];
    for(NSString *bundleId in identifiers) {
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:bundleId];
        if (bundle!=nil) break;
    }

    // try the main bundle
    if (bundle==nil) bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    // abort
    assert(bundle!=nil && "Missing bundle. Check the Bundle identifier on 
           the plist of this target vs the identifiers array in this class.");

    return bundle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was indeed the wrong Bundle! As I was trying to use a database from/within a Framework I 'simply' has to load the db from the corresponding `Bundle` !

Here is some code in Swift4 using `MagicalRecord`:

```
// Load the bundle
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: AClassFromTheFramework.self)
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [frameworkBundle])
// Use the new `managedObjectModel` by default
MagicalRecord.setShouldAutoCreateManagedObjectModel(false)
NSManagedObjectModel.mr_setDefaultManagedObjectModel(managedObjectModel)
// Load the database 
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: "db.sqlite")
```

And voilà!